# Animating alternating circles on canvas with gsap + scrolltrigger

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, gsap

https://codepen.io/handiworknyc/pen/GRYLjeE

Hi all, thanks in advance for your help.

I've never really used canvas before but i got pretty far with ChatGPT...

However ChatGPT was not good at getting these to animate with gsap.

How can I set it up so that these circles animate (i'm thinking a staggered fade in, the first row from the left and the second row from the right) when the canvas element scrolls into view using ScrollTrigger

```
var HW = {};

var $$ = function (selector, parent) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call((parent ? parent : document).querySelectorAll(selector));
};


var loop = function (arr, callback, method) {
    method = method || 'forEach';
    return Array.prototype[method].call(arr, callback);
};

HW.circMotif = function(canvas) {            
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            const circleSize = 80; // Size of the circles
            const padding = 3; // Padding between circle and square
            
            const canvasWidth = window.innerWidth + 6;
            const numRows = 2; // Number of rows
            
            // Calculate the square size based on the available width and padding
            const squareSize = (canvasWidth - 2 * padding) / Math.ceil(canvasWidth / (circleSize + 2 * padding));
            
            // Calculate the number of circles that can fit in a row
            const numCirclesPerRow = Math.floor(canvasWidth / squareSize);
            
            // Calculate the total width of the circles and padding
            const totalWidth = numCirclesPerRow * squareSize;
            
            // Calculate the left margin to center the circles
            const marginLeft = (canvasWidth - totalWidth) / 2;
            
            // Calculate the canvas height based on the number of rows
            const canvasHeight = numRows * squareSize;
            
            // Set the canvas dimensions
            canvas.width = canvasWidth;
            canvas.height = canvasHeight;
            
            // Clear the canvas
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            
            // Loop through the rows and columns to draw the circles
            for (let row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
                for (let col = 0; col < numCirclesPerRow; col++) {
                    // Calculate the x and y coordinates for the current circle
                    const x = marginLeft + col * squareSize;
                    const y = row * squareSize;
            
                    // Determine the starting color combination for each row
                    const isBlueCircle = ((row + col) % 2 === 0);
            
                    // Set the fill color and draw the square
                    ctx.fillStyle = (isBlueCircle) ? 'blue' : 'white';
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y, squareSize, squareSize);
            
                    // Draw the circle
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x + squareSize / 2, y + squareSize / 2, circleSize / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                    ctx.fillStyle = (isBlueCircle) ? 'white' : 'blue';
                    ctx.fill();
                }
            }
        }            
        
        HW.doCircMotif = function() {
            var $circleZazz = $$('.circle-zazz');
            
            loop($circleZazz, function(el){
               HW.circMotif(el);
            })
            
        }

            
            HW.doCircMotif();
```

Comment: This code shows exactly why ChatGPT is not ready to solve complete programming tasks yet. The code doesn't make much sense if all you want to do is draw circles. Also, the GSAP code is not in there yet, and you talk about a scroll detection :)  I recommend taking a step back to solve each problem one by one. Start with reading basic examples: draw a circle in canvas and animate a shape using GSAP. Both can be done in one line of code.

Comment: ... thanks ... the code works great just for drawing the circles.

Comment: yes, but there is "code pollution", a lot of unnecessary code. For example `var $$ = ...` and `var loop = ` make no sense at all.